# Distance between a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a ball

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B[a;r] \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed ball with center $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and radius $r > 0$.

For any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $d(x,B[a;r])$ (the distance between the ball and that point) being $max\{0,|x-a|-r\}$.

I started the proof suposing that $x \in B[a;r]$, and in that case, we have:

$$d(x,B[a;r])=0 \, \, \, \text{and} \, \, \, |x-a|\leq r \Rightarrow |x-a|-r \leq 0$$

Witch confirmes the affirmation of the proposition. But for $x \notin B[a;r]$, I know only that $d(x,B[a;r])>0$ and that exists $\overline{x} \in B[a;r]$ that $|x-\overline{x}| = d(x,B[a;r])$, but from there I can't proceed.

Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $y \in B(a, r)$  we have

$$|x-a| \le d(x,y) + |y-a|.$$
Hence
$$|x-a| \le d(x, y) + r.$$
Then
$$|x-a| - r \le d(x, y).$$
And
$$ |x-a| - r \le min d(x, y).$$
The min $d(x, y)$ is the minimum of $d(x, y)$  among all $y \in B(a, r)$.
The later is exactly the definition of $d(x, B(a, r)).$
So we deduced
$$ |x-a|- r  \le d(x, B(a, r)).$$
It remains the inverse of the inequality.